# Executing commands in a series in ubuntu terminal

Tags: batch-file, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Suppose I have a set of commands to be executed in ubuntu terminal:
for eg:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo install xrdp 
sudo install java
.....
```

and many others.

Is it possible in ubuntu to execute the file containing these commands and execute without human intervention (like yes/no) , by default yes?

I tried installing wine , executing $wine cmd /c Commands.bat , after putting all these commands in .bat file but getting errors "Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded."
So, is there any simple way of executing a series of commands in ubuntu?

Comment: Seriously dude? What in the hell did you smoke to get an idea as convoluted as "eh, I'm going to install Wine so I can run .bat files". You've got a perfectly fine working shell on your system. Probably even a whole variaty. Those are far more powerfull than the shell-wannabee called cmd.exe (there's a reason why there's a true shell for Windows called PowerShell inspired by Unix and Linux shells).

Comment: @datenwolf I did not read that part of the question. hehe! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are talking about - multiple commands in one file - is called a "shellscript".

Let's say you have `commands.sh`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo install xrdp 
sudo install java
```

Then you could execute the commands using:

```
bash commands.sh
```

---

You can also make a directly executable shellscript out of it using the so called [`shebang`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) mechanism.

Put this line on the very top (line 1) of `commands.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
```

.. and make the file executable:

```
chmod +x commands.sh
```

Now you can execute it directly:

```
./commands.sh
```

---

If you want to say "yes" to all questions, you can use the `yes` command:

```
yes | bash "file_with_commands.sh"
```

Comment: What if I have command that required password instead of password i.e svn command

Comment: They will ask for that password as if you would have typed them manually in terminal

Answer (score 6):

No need to do something convolutied and as insane as trying to make cmd.exe work. You already got a perfectly fine working shell on your system. Also you need to understand what programs like `sudo` do.

`sudo` is not some magic chant that enables something. `sudo` is a helper program that allows to start a program with elevated rights. Instead of having a chain of `sudo this` `sudo that` you can as just let sudo start a shell and pass a script with all those commands to the shell.

Turning

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo install xrdp 
> sudo install java
> ```

Into

```
sudo sh -c 'apt-get update ; install xrdp ; install java'
```

However that doesn't look right. I think you originally meant to write

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xrdp 
sudo apt-get install java
```

You can shorten this to

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xrdp java
```

Or in coalesced single liner shell

```
sudo sh -c 'apt-get update ; apt-get install xrdp java'
```

Now regarding the Yes/No questions. If a program you want to run unattended doesn't offer an option to give a default answer you can make use of the `yes` program. Even it being named  `yes` it can also answer NO or anything you like:

```
narfi /home/dw
1007 ~ % yes Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
…
```

How does this work? There's a concept called the "Standard Input / Output" from which programs read input from and write output to. Shells allow you to redirect the output from one program into the input of another one. This is called *pipe-ing*. The special character `|` designates a pipe in shells.

So say you've got a program that wants to see a large number of `Aye` inputs you could make the following call to the shell

```
yes Aye | happypirate
```

So you can combine this with apt-get to give all default yes answer writing

```
yes | apt-get install …
```

However this is barking up the wrong tree. Have a look at the call options for apt-get:

```
~ % apt-get --help
apt 0.9.7.6 for amd64 compiled on Oct 16 2012 18:23:06
Usage: apt-get [options] command
       apt-get [options] install|remove pkg1 [pkg2 ...]
       apt-get [options] source pkg1 [pkg2 ...]

apt-get is a simple command line interface for downloading and
installing packages. The most frequently used commands are update
and install.

…
  -y  Assume Yes to all queries and do not prompt    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
…
```

apt-get gives you an option to auto-answer all yes to all it questions. Neat, right? Note that other programs may use different option keys so you're well advised to always read their fine manuals (RTFM).

Comment: +1 For explaining that a lot of commands which would normally ask for confirmation also have a command line option to skip that confirmation - as `apt-get`. Yes, if they have such an option, it should being used.

Answer (score 2):

At its most basic level, you want to eecute a script. You do that by creating a file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo install xrdp 
sudo install java
```

Save that as a file called `go`, then in the Terminal, you need to make it executable like this:

```
chmod +x go
```

Then you can run it by typing:

```
./go
```

If your program expects an answer of "yes" for the first question, then "no" for the next question, you can prepare the answers in advance like this and send them into the program:

```
( echo yes; echo no ) | sudo apt-get update
```