# How to run bat file using java code in ubuntu?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a selenium project. I want to run my bat file using java code in ubuntu(Can I run a batch file inside a jar?)

But after all search everyone is giving me cmd based code which will only run in windows, I need a code which can be run in mac/Linux terminal as well

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start build.bat");
```

Above is the command I have found for windows but what about mac/linux

Comment: Did you try googling your answer? I did.

Comment: It's also a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528291/executing-commands-in-a-series-in-ubuntu-terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Batch files are DOS scripts, they don't run on Linux.

*.bat* file cannot be run on ubuntu, You can create *.sh* file instead of *.bat* to run on UNIX/Linux environment.

*.bat* file is a windows batch file it contains a sequence of windows/dos commands.

*.sh* file is a UNIX shell script it contains a series of UNIX commands.

Please click on link [here](http://linuxcommand.org/writing_shell_scripts.php) to know more about how .sh file can be created.

Comment: can you please provide any sh file syntax which can run my testng xml file similar like bash